# move_uploaded_file returns false, but $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] == 0

Tags: php, image

I am using the POST method to upload a photo in my upload_photo.php file which uses uploader.php to process the image.  Uploader.php will resize the image and overwrite the old one.  It works fine locally, but not on the server.

`move_uploaded_file` returns false, but `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] == 0` which does not make since to me.

I have posted the entire uploader.php and a snippet from upload_photo.php which shows the form tag.

```
<?php
//This is uploader.php
session_start();
include ('dbconfig.php');
include('SimpleImage.php');

mysql_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
$conn = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . renameImage();

$_SESSION['client_photo'] = $target_path;

$query = "UPDATE client ";
$query .= "SET personal_photo = ('$target_path') ";
$query .= "WHERE client_id = ".$_SESSION['clientID'];
$results = mysql_query($query) or die('Error msg: '.mysql_error().'<br/>
        sql: '.query.'<br/>');

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
  $msg = "The file ".  $_SESSION['client_photo']. 
  " has been uploaded";
  chmod($target_path, "0666");
  $work = new ImgResizer($target_path); 
  $work -> resize(600, $target_path); 
} else{
  $msg = "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
  $msg .= $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'];
}
header("Location: upload_photo.php?msg=$msg");

function renameImage(){ 
  mysql_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
  $conn = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

  $sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, client_id
          FROM client
          WHERE client_id = ".$_SESSION['clientID'];
  $res = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error msg: '.mysql_error().'<br/>
                sql: '.$sql.'<br/>');
  if($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      $_SESSION['successphoto'] = 1;
      return $row{first_name}.'_'.$row{last_name}.'_'.$row{client_id};
  }
  else{
      echo "There was an error while fetching the row.<br/>";
  }
}

class ImgResizer {
  private $originalFile = '';
  public function __construct($originalFile = '') {
      $this -> originalFile = $originalFile;
  }
  public function resize($newWidth, $targetFile) {
      if (empty($newWidth) || empty($targetFile)) {
          return false;
      }
      $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($this -> originalFile);
      list($width, $height) = getimagesize($this -> originalFile);
      $newHeight = ($height / $width) * $newWidth;
      $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
      imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
      if (file_exists($targetFile)) {
          unlink($targetFile);
      }
      imagejpeg($tmp, $targetFile, 85); // 85 is my choice, make it between 0 – 100 for output image quality with 100 being the most luxurious
  }
}

?>
```

Here is the snippet from upload_photo.php

```
echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">';
echo '<tr>';
//echo "<td colspan='2'>".$_GET['text']."</td>";
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr align="center">';
echo '<td colspan="2">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5000000" />
        Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" accept="image/*"/><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
      </form>';
```

Comment: Can you check if you have write permissions where you are trying to move the uploaded file?

Comment: Depending on where your php file is, $target_path may be wrong. I don't know your site structure but try this : $target_path = '/uploads/';

Comment: @mazzucci Here are the permissions for uploads: drwxrwxrwx 2 root     root    4096 Nov 16 15:40 uploads

Comment: @jeromesmadja Here is the $targetpath for a specific file: uploads/__90748.  This should be correct.  Also, I don't think the chmod function is working properly, because it works locally if I comment out the permissions.  I do think this is a permissions issue, but I'm not sure how to overcome it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That probably means that the upload went through okay - the file is uploaded to your temp directory - but the file could not be moved to the destination you have set.

You should double-check the path you are moving the file to and make sure that the web user (`apache`, `www` or whatever) has permissions to write to that directory.

Comment: Here are the permissions for uploads: drwxrwxrwx 2 root     root    4096 Nov 16 15:40 uploads

Comment: I do think it's a permissions issue, but I'm not sure what the correct permissions are.

Comment: @rharrison33 There is no reason to make it world-writable, just change the ownership to the web-user and make sure the owner can write. Are you absolutely sure that the path is correct? You are using a relative path, so perhaps it is not what you think it is.

Comment: $jeroen My uploads/ directory is in the same directory as uploader.php so I'm pretty sure it is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely you are in the right path. Just change the directory permissions like below. Hope it will work.

```
chmod 777 uploaded_folder_name
```